# Flash: Align text verticaly

Tags: flash, flash-cs3

is possible to align text in dynamic text control vertically to the middle? In flash CS3. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will have to do it programmatically:

```
var textField:TextField = new TextField();
textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
// ... some code here ...

var fullHeight:int = 100;
textField.y = (fullHeight - textField.height)*.5;
```